# Grails Atmosphere Plugin broadcast to different clients

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I'm trying to extend the Groovy Mag Atmosphere Example (https://github.com/rbramley/GroovyMagJMS) to broadcast to different clients. (Like in [Broadcasting to a subset of subscribers in Atmosphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199164/broadcasting-to-a-subset-of-subscribers-in-atmosphere))

A client connects with url http://localhost:8080/GrailsTest/atmosphere/messages/?id=1. An id will be passed to the server. The new added lookupBroadcaster Method creates a new Broadcaster Object with the id. When I wanna broadcast a message, the client does not receive the result.

Can somebody help me and maybe try it out?

I'm added the atmosphere 0.8.2 library to BuildConfig.groovy to use mappings like '/atmosphere/messages/*'.

```
dependencies {  
    runtime 'org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:0.8.2'
}


class AtmosphereService {

static transactional = false

static atmosphere = [mapping: '/atmosphere/messages/*']

static exposes = ['jms']

@Subscriber(topic='msgevent')
def onEvent(msg) {
    println 'onevent'
    def payload = msg
    if(msg instanceof Map) {
        // convert map messages to JSON
        payload = msg.encodeAsJSON()
    }

    Broadcaster b = lookupBroadcaster(msg["id"], false);
    b.broadcast(payload)

    return null
}

Broadcaster lookupBroadcaster(String id, Boolean createBroadcast) {
    return BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(id, createBroadcast)
}

def onRequest = { event ->

    def req = event.request
    def id = req.getParameter("id")

    Broadcaster b = lookupBroadcaster(id, true);
    event.setBroadcaster(b);
    b.addAtmosphereResource(event)

    event.suspend()

}

def onStateChange = { event ->
    if (event.message) {
        log.info "onStateChange, message: ${event.message}"

        if (event.isSuspended()) {
            event.resource.response.writer.with {
                write "<script>parent.callback('${event.message}');</script>"
                flush()
            }
            event.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That should work based on that code snippet. Is the `onStateChange()` method invoked when you broadcast? Since you are resuming, the first broadcast will works but after that the AtmosphereResource will be removed from its associated Broadcaster, hence no more update.